# Mail.app keeps crashing: Got EXPUNGE but EXISTS is already 0

Tags: macos, mail.app

Mail.app on my High Sierra (it also did this on Sierra too) keeps crashing. In the error report I see that it always crashes with the same error:

`Got EXPUNGE but EXISTS is already 0`.

What does this mean and how do I avoid crashes?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, with it happening a few times a day but only when sending email. Rebuilding the mailbox did not help.

Eventually I found that I was storing draft messages on the server. This is picked in **Mail > Preferences > someemailaccount > Mailbox Behaviours > Drafts Mailbox**.

I changed that to a local "On My Mac" setting. I have not had a single error today and yesterday since doing so!

I think what was happening was my mail provider was sending the message *and* deleting the message from drafts, in the meantime, Apple Mail wanted to delete the message from drafts, and, they clashed depending on which happened first.